# Type inferring in Java8 & Vertx

Tags: java-8, vert.x

According to documentation, `executeBlocking` method of `Vertx` interface has following signature:

```
<T> void executeBlocking(Handler<Future<T>> blockingCodeHandler, boolean ordered, Handler<AsyncResult<T>> resultHandler)
```

The question is, why (from formal perspective) following makes Java unable to infer generic type for `Future<T>` (it's inferred to `Future<Object>`):

```
    vertx.executeBlocking((deploymentFuture) -> {
        this.deploy();
        deploymentFuture.complete(new Boolean(true));
    }, (asyncResult) -> {
        start.complete();
    });
```

Even though `deploymentFuture` is clearly assigned with `Boolean`. Only this explicit call gives Java idea of `Future<Boolean>`:

```
    vertx.<Boolean>executeBlocking((deploymentFuture) -> {
        this.deploy();
        deploymentFuture.complete(new Boolean(true));
    }, (asyncResult) -> {
        start.complete();
    });
```

Why it's so problematic to infer types in such use case? Is is because type invariance (similar case to `ArrayList<Integer>` vs `ArrayList<Number>`).

Basically without explicit call type I'm thrown away with

`No instances of type variable T exist so that Future<T> conforms to Future<Object>`

Comment: `deploymentFuture` is not “assigned with `Boolean`”. You are trying to invoke a method on `deploymentFuture`, but invoking a method on a variable is never used to determine the type of the variable. By the way, there is no sense in constructing a `new Boolean(…)`. Just use `true` and it will be boxed to the constant `Boolean.TRUE` when an object is needed

Comment: @Holger don't you mind to transfer comment into answer? The usage of `new Boolean(...)` was just an act of desperation in chase of being as explicit as possible.